# How do I smoothly and simultaneously expand/compress a parent div and reveal an inner child on hover with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

CODE SAMPLE HERE: http://codepen.io/colbisaurusrex/pen/YZdKyO?editors=1100

First problem:
I am trying to smoothly expand and compress a div (`class: event`) on hover. It expands smoothly, but it snaps back quickly when user is no longer hovering on div. I'd like to transition back at the same ease as it expands

Second problem:
Simultaneously, I'd like to reveal an inner, hidden child(`class: hidden`) when I hover over its parent(`class: event`). Ideally, I'd like to reveal it when the parent is fully expanded. And ease it back to hidden as the parent compresses. Right now, it is revealed immediately, before the parent div is fully expanded. I have tried to add a delay.

Basically, there is a beginning and ending transition that exact mirrors of each other. I'd like to do this with no Javascript

Bonus Question: If the entire transition was set off by a button click(say the `Show Details` button), do I have to use JS? Is there a way to do this with CSS only?

```
/* This is the CSS I am working with */

.event {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 960px; 
  border-color:#496DD9;
  border-style: dotted; 
  font-size: 0.5em; 
  height: 250px; 
  transform: height 300ms ease-out; 
}

.event:hover {
   height: 300px;
   transition: height 500ms ease-in;   
}

.event:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
  transition: display 300ms ease-in 1s;  
}

.hidden {
  font-size: 30px; 
  display: none; 
}

/* End of css */
```

Comment: Are you afraid that javascript will bite or something? `button:first-of-type:active ~ .hidden {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s;
}` is the closest you'll most likely get to having any effect on that element with an interaction on that button using only CSS. If you change your button to an anchor tag then you could go so far as to have it remained displayed - until the user clicks somewhere else, `a.show-details:first-of-type:focus ~ .hidden {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s;
}`

Comment: No, I love Javascript. But I am trying to get better with CSS.

Comment: Ok. Great. If javascript is like hunting big game, CSS is like shooting fish in a barrel. I'm sure you'll love it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem 1: `transform` should be `transition`

```
.event {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 960px; 
  border-color:#496DD9;
  border-style: dotted; 
  font-size: 0.5em; 
  height: 250px; 
  transform: height 300ms ease-out; // change this to transition
}
```

Problem 2: try using `opacity` instead of `display`:

```
.event:hover .hidden {
/*   display: block; */
/*   transition: display 500ms ease-in 1s;   */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  font-size: 30px; 
/*   display: none;  */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpeWZz?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks! That works great. FYI, needed to `-webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;` and change the transition hover in  `.event:hover .hidden` to `ease-in`